# is there a way to keep router query on page refresh in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a dynamic page with a dynamic url. everything is clientside rendered.

This is the `link` that links to the second page

```
<Link
href= {{ pathname: '/dashboard/[orderdetail]', query: { id: `${orderID}` } }} as={`/dashboard/${orderDetails.orderNo}`}
</Link>
```

This works well taking every query to the second page. But when I refresh the second page, everything is lost. Every query i had passed is lost

I have tried using `with/Router`

```
let orderID=this.props.router.query.orderdetail;
```

Still on page refresh everything is lost.

I need the `query string` i am passing to the second page to make a call to a database which works well. But again, when I refresh the page nothing works.

How can I avoid this loss when the page refreshes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end I ended up with this solution, there is no difference here

```
               <Link
                 href={{
                  pathname: "/dashboard/" + `${orderDetails.orderNo}`,
                  query: { id: `${orderID}` },
                }} as={`/dashboard/${orderDetails.orderNo}`}
              >
              </Link>
```

but adding this in the second page somehow maintains the route query.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

How this solves the problem, I don't know, but it does. I do not think there will be that much difference considering I only wanted client-side rendering

Comment: I also don't know how it works, but worked for me as well :)

Comment: x2 its works for me but I really dont know why... :(

Comment: "params: If this page uses a dynamic route, params contains the route parameters. If the page name is [id].js , then params will look like { id: ... }. To learn more, take a look at the Dynamic Routing documentation." https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

Comment: Same here... I don't quite know how it works, but it does the job! :D Thanks Taio

Comment: In my case , `getServerSideProps` can not be used for next export

Comment: Thanks for posting this op. I am also passing query params for database calls and when I saw this solution I was super skeptical.  I copied and pasted the above getSersideProps outside of my client function and it worked upon refresh. I'm shocked, but relieved!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is some confusion about what query parameters you are working with.

With the `href` URL object you have in your example the resulting full href URL will be:

```
/dashboard/[order]?id=nnn
```

so `router.query` will contain an `order` key and an `id` key, but no `orderdetail`.

The `order` key will be set to the content of `orderDetails.orderNo` with your given `as` property, but the `id` will not be set since `as` has no `?id=xxx` part.

Assuming your JS filename is `/pages/dashboard/[order].js`, your ${orderDetails.orderNo} is accessible as `this.props.router.query.order` and the `id` query string is never used.

`this.props.router.query.orderdetail` as in your code from the question will never be set to anything since the request has no such parameter name.

If instead the filename is `/pages/dashboard/[orderdetail].js` you need the corresponding

```
<Link href="/dashboard/[orderdetail]" as={`/dashboard/${orderDetails.orderNo}`}>...</Link>
```

Comment: What I was wondering actually is why I cannot access the http://localhost:3000/dashboard/601020 last number there 601020. When I refresh it remains in the url bar but the router query loses it

Comment: What do you mean by "tosses it"? It should be accessible as `this.props.router.query.order`

Comment: Exactly, it comes off empty I dont know why

Comment: What is the filename of the JS file? Which NextJS version are you using?

Comment: You did notice that in the code in your question you are referring to `this.props.router.query.orderdetail`? "orderdetail" is not the correct name, the query parameter is "order".

Comment: I corrected it, it should be orderdetail. The filename is [orderdetail].js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214176/discussion-between-taio-and-jesper-we).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by using pure JS to access the query string values. When [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) is used, Next will generate the page on the server-side for each incoming request. To avoid this server-side latency add the `useEffect()` hook to access the `window` object and from there retrieve the query string.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let queryString = window.location.search;
    let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    var studentId = urlParams.get("id");
}, []);
```

To access different query string values simply change the `urlParms.get("id")` to use the name of the query string variable you're looking for. I preferred this solution because I wanted to keep this functionality on the client and avoid adding unnecessary stuff to the server. This is also cool because you avoid using the `useRouter()` hook.

Comment: liked this answer because it just works

router has a loading time in which useEffect starts with router not loaded