# Query values lost on page refresh in Next js? [Example given]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am making a simple Next Js application which has only two pages..

**index.tsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link
        href={{
          pathname: "/about",
          query: { candidateId: 8432 }
        }}
        as="about"
      >
        Go to the about page
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As per the above code, on click `Go to the about page` it goes to about page and using `query` I also receive the passed query values in about page.

**about.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import Router, { withRouter } from "next/router";

function About({ router: { query } }: any) {
  return (
    <div>
      Candidate Id: <b> {query.candidateId} </b>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(About);
```

This displays the value but on page refresh while we are in `/about` page, the `candidateId` received gets disappeared.

**Requirement:** Kindly help me to retain the query value passed down from one page to another page even on page refresh.

**Note:** As per my requirement I should not display the `canidateId` on url while navigating and hence I am using `as` approach.. I know I can achieve it if I remove `as` but I cannot remove that here in index page while navigating.. Reason is this will lead to displaying candidateId in the url which is not intended..

Tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62974489/7785337 but this gives **empty query** object on refresh of page.

Stuck for very long time with this please kindly help me.

[image: Edit dawn-microservice-sho7z]

Comment: AFAIK, "route state" is fairly transient, it really only exists *during* the route transition. Reloading the page doesn't reload the transition. I think you would need to persist the passed data to localStorage, or whatever you have available, that is accessible after a page load/reload.

Comment: @DrewReese, Thanks for your comment and I think some other people also facing the same issue like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891845/is-there-a-way-to-keep-router-query-on-page-refresh-in-nextjs and the proposed solution dosn't work for me.. If you could help me then please fork my codesandbox with your solution and post it as answer please.. I am just requesting if you could to do.. Because I see things in a different way from yours and I am learning a lot from you.. Please help me if you could .. Thanks..

Comment: @DrewReese, Bro can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504354/variable-not-defined-in-react-typescript ?

Comment: @DrewReese, Can we make use of React context api in such case?

Comment: Looks like TJ has a pretty good handle on that one. I don't disagree with anything he's said there. Without seeing your actual code and based entirely on his word and my examination of the react-metrics docs I'd say, yeah, the React Context API could potentially help here, though it seems react-metrics may already have its own context and provider.

Comment: @DrewReese, Bro I have also offered a bounty to my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/65699046/13270726 .. Please help me bro.. I expect a detailed answer from  you and I believe in your solution much, So do the needful bro.. Big thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use the query parameter you may need to create a "store" that saves your variable that persist throughout your pages.

Sample code as follows.

```
//candidatestore.js
export const CandidateStoreContext = createContext()

export const useCandidateStore = () => {
    const context = useContext(CandidateStoreContext)
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error(`useStore must be used within a CandidateStoreContext`)
    }
    return context
}

export const CandidateStoreProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [candidateId, setCandidateId] = useState(null);

    return (
        <CandidateStoreContext.Provider value={{ candidateId, setCandidateId }}>        
                        {children}    
        </CandidateStoreContext.Provider >

    )
}
```

Then you need to wrap the Provider around your app like

```
<CandidateStoreProvider><App /></CandidateStoreProvider>
```

This way you can use anywhere as follows both in your index page and your about page.

```
const { candidateId, setCandidateId } = useCandidateStore()
```

[UseContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

In your codes, it should probably look something like that.

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useCandidateStore } from './candidatestore'

export default function Index() {
  const { candidateId, setCandidateId } = useCandidateStore()
  useEffect(() => {
     setCandidateId(thecandidateId)
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <Link
        href={{
          pathname: "/about",
        }}
        as="about"
      >
        Go to the about page
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

function About({ router: { query } }: any) {

  const { candidateId, setCandidateId } = useCandidateStore()
  return (
    <div>
      Candidate Id: <b> {candidateId} </b>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update to Next.JS 10. It comes with [Automatic Resolving of href](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10#automatic-resolving-of-href) which fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the `as="about"` and then navigate again to the "about" page, the issue should be gone.
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-snowflake-l1bts?file=/pages/index.tsx)

Comment: I have already mentioned in question that this will work if I delete ```as``` but I shouldn't because that will lead to displaying ```candidateId``` in the url..

Answer (score 1):

My best bet would be to store the `candidateId` in an encrypted session on the client side. You could read/verify cookies in `getServerSideProps()` and pass their contents to the page component. If this sounds feasible, I'd recommend checking out the [next-iron-session](https://github.com/vvo/next-iron-session).

Another approach would be to check if `candidateId` exists in the query object in `getServerSideProps()`. If it does then pass it straight to the page component. If not, either get it elsewhere, redirect, or pass some default value. Append the following starter code to your **about.tsx**:

```js
/* ... */

export function getServerSideProps({ query }: any) {
  // if query object was received, return it as a router prop:
  if (query.candidateId) {
    return { props: { router: { query } } };
  }
  // obtain candidateId elsewhere, redirect or fallback to some default value:
  /* ... */
  return { props: { router: { query: { candidateId: 8432 } } } };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**index.tsx file**

Keep the code same as it is.

```
   import React from "react";
   import Link from "next/link";
   
   export default function Index() {
     return (
       <div>
         <Link
           href={{
             pathname: "/about",
             query: { candidateId: 8432 }
           }}
           as="about"
         >
           Go to the about page
         </Link>
       </div>
     );
}
```

**AboutUs.tsx**

**Code starts from here**

Adding router as a dependency in the useEffect the issue should get solved.

```
  import Router, { useRouter } from "next/router";
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

  function About({ router: { query } }: any) {
    const route = userRouter();
    const [candidateId, setCandidateid] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
    const {candidateId} = router.query  
    if(candidateId) {
     setCandidateid(candidateid)
   }},[router])  //Here goes the dependency

    return (
      <div>
        Candidate Id: <b> {candidateId} </b>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default (About);
```