# Variable not defined in React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am making a simple React application in which there is a **app.tsx** file with the code as follows,

```
export default function App() {
  const initializeData = () => {
    const dataScript = document.createElement("script");
    dataScript.type = "text/javascript";
    dataScript.textContent = `
    let data = { 'name': "" };`;
    document.head.appendChild(dataScript);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    initializeData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log(data)}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**->** Where **initializeData** method will intialize a global data and that will be available for all other pages (considering all components will be called from here in `app.tsx` ).

**->** Calling the method from `useEffect` lifecycle hook like,

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    initializeData();
  }, []);
```

**->** Trying to `console.log` the data in template like,

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log(data)}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
```

**Error:**

This line  `{console.log(data)}` throws the error as **data is not defined**

**Requirement:**

Need to make a variable declaration in global level so those variables would be available for all files.

Keeping this in mind only I have tried assigning it in `head` tag inside `script` tag but this shows error in typescript.

[image: Edit stupefied-newton-ixwut]

Please help me on how to assign a global variable and access it inside any files..

Comment: *"Need to make a variable declaration in global level so those variables would be available for all files."* Using globals at all in a modern JS/TS page or app is not best practice without a **very** strong reason to do it, but creating a global variable when a component mounts is never a good idea. Whatever your underlying requirement is, I strongly recommend you find another way to solve it. Ideally, don't use a global at all (you really shouldn't need to in a world with modules), but if you cant avoid it, at least create it when the module is loaded, not later when the component is mounted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I am using like this to handle adobe analytics for the page.. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-metrics to track the events and for that I am in the need to set a global variable and it will get changed on every page.. Like whichever page we are visiting then that page name (along with other data) will be passed down to metrics track function..

Comment: I don't see anything on that npm page suggesting you need to use a global variable. I do see it saying you need to wrap your application component via a call to `metrics` which you don't seem to be doing above. (My guess is that it's doing that in order to set up a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) that `MetricsElement`s and such can use, but that's just a guess.) But I don't want to get into a back-and-forth about whether you need a global variable. Your question was about why `data` doesn't exist, which I've answered below. Happy coding!

Comment: Looks like an XY problem https://xyproblem.info/, you asking about your attempt instead of tackling the real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` callback doesn't run until **after** your attempt to use the `data` variable in the JSX you're returning. From the [`useEffect` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

> The function passed to `useEffect` will run **after** the render is committed to the screen.

The order in which things happen when your `App` function is first called is:

1. The `initializeData` function is created.
2. Your `useEffect` callback function is created.
3. `useEffect` is called with that callback and an empty array.
4. Your JSX is evaluated, including the `console.log(data)` call — causing the error.

If it weren't for the error, things would continue like this:

5. The React element (and its children) you return would be put in the DOM by React.
6. *Then* React would call your `useEffect` callback, which would create the script element creating the global variable.

You *could* use `typeof data === "undefined"` to know that it's the first render and `data` may not exist yet, but you'll also need to do something else to make your component function get called again (e.g., have a state variable you update in your `useEffect` callback). But creating a global variable when a component mounts is, to put it mildly, not best practice and I strongly recommend you look to solve your underlying requirement in a different way.

Comment: Even if you fix the `useEffect` how can you use the `data` variable globally without appending it to a global object?

Comment: @DennisVash - `let` declarations at global scope create globals, even though they don't create properties on the global object. (There are something like six layers of globals in the browser environment, at least two of which are defined by JavaScript itself.) So the OP's script they're injecting will create a global called `data` eventually. Just not in time for the JSX to use it the first time `App` is called. :-) The *second* call would have access to it, if one occurred.

Comment: Yea you right I checked it: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-wood-c455x?file=/src/App.tsx, nice one

Comment: If you're interested in this stuff, I -- er -- go into `let` and `const` in some detail in Chapter 2 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile. :-D (Though I don't go into the six layers of globals. I need to do a blog post on that, it's been coming up a lot lately...)